# How to connect to internet using "rasdial <connection name>" method in cmd

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line, windows-8.1, internet-connection

I am able to directly connect to internet using network connection interface shown below
 [image]

but I'm not able to connect to the net using cmd. with the following code.

```
rasdial "TATA PHOTON+"
```

Progress:

```
C:\Users\Admin>rasdial "TATA PHOTON+" Connecting to TATA PHOTON+... Verifying username and password...
```

and then I get the following error

```
Remote Access error 691 - The remote connection was denied because the user name and password combination you provided is not recognized, or the selected authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server.
```

It seems I needs to provide username and password. If that's the problem how can I provide username and password Or is there any other problem?

Comment: Did you try rasdial *connectionname* *username* *password*?

Comment: Oh no I'll try if it works and just notify, please wait a moment.

Comment: @Karan Problem solved! I typed rasdial "connectionname" username as suggested by Karan in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use rasdial [*connectionname*] [*username*] [*password* | *]

(Entering * should prompt you for the password.)

Answer (score 0):

Q&A type response...

The problem was with not typing the username. Instead of typing `rasdial "<connectionname>"`
I typed `rasdial "<connectionname>" <username>` which solved the problem.
If your network connection is password protected you have to type `rasdial "<connectionname>" <username> <password>`